# I want to implement a small and fast qualitative data type in Fortran

Tags: types, fortran

This is part of a series of questions about implementing a qualitative data type in Fortran.

**Background:** The topic relates to something called *loop analysis of complex systems* which one might read about in, for example, Puccia, C. J. and Levins, R. (1986). *Qualitative Modeling of Complex Systems: An Introduction to Loop Analysis and Time Averaging*. Harvard University Press, Cambridge, MA, or Levins, R. (1974). The qualitative analysis of partially specified systems. *Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences*, 231:123–138. While I could implement this technique using numerical matrix algebra (as has been done elsewhere), I am interested in approaching the problem from a different direction. The nature of loop analysis is complex and costly (I am not a CS person, but I think it's something like a #P difficulty calculation), and my long term aims are to create a set of libraries for various and sundry loop analysis problems that employ pruning optimizations based on properties of qualitative arithmetic. If this seems hopelessly misguided, please humor me and consider this an exercise in learning.

For my purposes the QUALIT data type can have 4 values: -1, 0, +1, and ? (sometimes represented as -, 0, +, and +/- in the literature).

I might implement this using two logical elements:

```
bit2  bit1  value
0      0     -1
0      1      0
1      0      1
1      1      ?
```

Or in Fortan:

```
TYPE QUALIT
  LOGICAL bit2, bit1
  END TYPE
```

There are arithmetic operations on QUALIT data which are different than sign arithmetic in standard math packages, and which will be the subject of different questions. My question here:

Is deriving a type with two logical variables as I have done above the smallest (memory) and fastest (in terms of manipulating such data) way to define the QUALIT data type? I am going to want to do a large number of arithmetic operations with them (including arithmetic and conditional testing); I am also going to want to create arrays with elements of type QUALIT and perform many operations on these data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this, and your other two questions (and both parts of those questions), is at best "It Depends".  "No" without elaboration might also suffice, given the way you've written the actual questions.

The answer is almost certainly hardware (assuming you are even solving these problems on a computer...), software and problem detail (particularly problem size) specific.

I'd suggest that you need to construct a prototype for testing, set some calculations up on representative data, and measure time and memory requirements.  Note that the smallest solution may not be the fastest solution, and the fastest solution may depend on problem size.

Variations that you should consider include using other than default kind logical.  The storage for default kind logical has to be the same as for default kind integer and default kind real, which always going to be much larger than the nominal one bit of storage required to hold a true or false value.

The obvious alternative implementation is to encode the four values for the datatype in a small range integer, perhaps even using the bit intrinsics.  Whether that ends up being faster or smaller ... it depends.

You may also want to rethink your mapping from logical components/bits through to the four values, given the operations that you want to perform on thee values in other questions and how they could be represented using the normal logical operations (and/or/ eqv/neqv, etc).  Consider a component or bit that represents "is negative", and one that represents "is positive".  You may (or may not) find that simply using the basic logical operations gives a faster result than you precomputed table approach, used in the other two questions, particularly given the logical operations inherent in calculating table indices.

Another important metric in choosing an approach, beyond speed and memory footprint, is the clarity and usability of the resulting code.  In many situations, this is really the most important metric.

Comment: This can be said more emphatically 'no' on the storage question. The smallest storage of any single variable type is a whole *byte* for any mainstream compiler. You can use a single `integer(kind=1)` for each 2-bit value and use half the space. (assuning your compiler supports it..)

Comment: @IanH: can you amplify "simply using the basic logical operations gives a faster result than you precomputed table approach, used in the other two questions" with an example? (on the actual page with the appropriate operation, if you please).